# $.ajax and JSONP.Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I keep getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, and I can not for the life of me , figure out why.

```
    function democracyMap(resp) {
    representative.fullName = resp.jurisdictions[5].elected_office[0].name_full;
    representative.face = resp.jurisdictions[5].elected_office[0].url_photo;
    representative.district = resp.jurisdictions[5].name;

    senator1.fullName = resp.jurisdictions[6].elected_office[0].name_full;
    senator1.face = resp.jurisdictions[6].elected_office[0].url_photo;

    senator2.fullName = resp.jurisdictions[6].elected_office[1].name_full;
    senator2.face = resp.jurisdictions[6].elected_office[1].url_photo;

    representativeInfo();
    senator1Info();
    senator2Info();
    apiSuccess();
}


function ajaxFail(req, status, err) {
    console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
}

function getDemocracyMap(){     

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.democracymap.org/",
        data:"location=",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",          
        success: function(resp) {
            democracyMap(resp);
        },
        error: ajaxFail
    });
}
```

Each representative, as well as sentator 1 and senator are set as global variables as such:

```
var representative = {
    "fullName": "",
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "district": "",
    "face": "",
    "party": "",
    "termStart": "",
    "termEnd": "",
    "facebookID": "",
    "twitter": "",
    "youTube": ""
}
```

Comment: looks like jsonp is not supported by the API

Comment: The URL you're using is for the documentation of the API, it's not the API itself.

Comment: also CORS is not supported... so I don't think you can use the API from the client side(browser) using ajax calls..

Comment: The api call should look like http://api.democracymap.org/context?location=chicago

Comment: One possible solution is make sure web server act like a proxy and sent the ajax request to your server which will in tern sent a request to the remote source and collect its response then sent it back to the client